# How to describe the type of analysis which use large Electronic Health Records? meta analysis? big data analysis?

Tags: meta-analysis

I have got access to large amount of EHR (electronic health records) of one of the largest health insurance in my country. I intend to pull out some clinical parameters and analyze them using machine learning methods, how would you define this analysis as a meta-analysis or just a regular one? or a big data analysis?

I would really appreciate your answers,
Thanks you!!
Ed.

Comment: It seems unlikely that this could be a meta-analysis.